# How to prevent open files error when using APScheduler/Flask on server

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I'm using the [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library with Flask to run tasks on an Ubuntu server. It will run fine for several days, but eventually the Flask process will error out with the following message:

```
(libdev) error creating signal/async pipe: Too many open files
```

I'm honestly at a loss to why this is happening or how I can prevent it in the future. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe create a functionality that close the file after you open them, or you could get the process ID of them and kill them "kill -9 PID"

Comment: This has nothing directly to do with APScheduler. Knowing nothing more about this project of yours I cannot say more.

Comment: Do you not get a traceback for this error?

Comment: This error appears when running a small Flask app that schedules Python jobs using APScheduler. When I look in HTOP, I can see the job, which is run with `python app.py` has dozens of PIDs active. So I'm guessing that this is what is causing this system error.